# How do I find an replace a string across multiple files in a dir recursively

Tags: bash

I'm on mac, and I want to find all strings that match `string_to_replace` and replace them with `new_string`

Comment: You don't want to edit the text; you want to edit a particular JSON object. Let a tool like `jq` handle the parsing and re-serialization for you.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Edited both the question and answer to make it a simple text instead of json

Answer (score 1):

Use find and exec

```
[mymac]$ find . -name model.txt -exec sed -i .bak 's/string_to_replace/new_string/g' {} +
```

On mac (or perhaps all BSD based systems), a backup file is mandatory. If you don't need the backup file, delete it

```
[mymac]$ find . -name model.txt.bak -exec rm {} +
```